# Error on connection to the remote server

Tags: android, httpconnection

I am trying to connect to the server through login window. When I entered the username & password and click on the button, it shows me an error that the app is stopped and the following is the .java code and logcat:

```
package com.example.sh.mysqldemo;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;



public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url ="http://166.87.228.72/loging.php";
        if (type.equals("login")) try {
            String user_name = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

and the **logcat** is the below:

> 4-12 10:15:53.764 12350-12371/com.example.sh.mysqldemo
>   D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using
>   platform default 04-12 10:15:53.776
>   12350-12371/com.example.sh.mysqldemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.sh.mysqldemo, PID: 12350
>                                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
>                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast
>   to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.sh.mysqldemo.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:41)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.sh.mysqldemo.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:25)
>                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
>                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                            at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)  04-12 10:15:54.397
>   12350-12365/com.example.sh.mysqldemo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent:
>   0xa9505120: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa95032b0) 04-12 10:15:54.404
>   12350-12365/com.example.sh.mysqldemo D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   endAllActiveAnimators on 0x999ae180 (RippleDrawable) with handle
>   0x9e65c500

Answer (score 1):

You would use the javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection class, not java.net.HttpURLConnection.

Comment: Do you mean I should import it or what?